# PHP - fopen: failed to open stream: Invalid argument

Tags: php, curl, fopen

i have a constant `DOCROOT` which is equal to `C:\wamp\www\playground\`, and I see nothing wrong with my current code:

```
$url = 'http://0.tqn.com/f/lg/a148.png';
$filename = 'love.png';

    $ch = curl_init($url);
    $fp = fopen(DOCROOT.'img2/'.$filename, 'wb');
    curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_FILE, $fp);
    curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_HEADER, 0);
    curl_exec($ch);
    curl_close($ch);
    fclose($fp);
```

The error is: `fopen(C:\wamp\www\playground\img2/499511971screen0.png ) [function.fopen]: failed to open stream: Invalid argument`. Why is it so? I tried to see related questions and the answer was something about double quotes which i'm not using.

Comment: What is your path separator? backslash, I'd say. You're using forward slash after img2

Comment: I fixed it, i `trim()`ed on the parameters. LoL

Answer (score 2):

Try surrounding the path with [realpath](http://php.net/manual/en/function.realpath.php) or something equivalent. It will transform all slashes to the ones your operating system understands (in your case, change the forward slash to a backslash).